# Python word recognize in a list

Tags: python

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    text.split()
    print text.split()
    for w in words:
        count += 1
    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These unit tests are only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert count_words(u"How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {u"how", u"are", u"you", u"hello"}) == 3, "Example"
    assert count_words(u"Bananas, give me bananas!!!", {u"banana", u"bananas"}) == 2, "BANANAS!"
    assert count_words(u"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                   {u"sum", u"hamlet", u"infinity", u"anything"}) == 1, "Weird text"
```

Ok I got the following problem the count result is 4 (I don't know how is that possible).

The result should be instead of 4 it should be 3

Comment: you have typo and bad indentation. pls correct it

Comment: 1. The code isn't syntactically valid. 2. You haven't told us what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: how u mean correct it

Comment: The code is supposed to get count up to 3 but I get count up to 3               Look bellow asser results it should recognize the words and add them to count

Answer (score 3):

You're code doesn't make much sense, you write lines like:

```
print text.split(9
```

Where you open a bracket and don't close it.

Furthermore your algorithm:

```
for w in words:
    count += 1
return count
```

Doesn't make much sense: you simply count the number of words.

The method you look for is:

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    for w in words:
        if w in text:
            count += 1
    return count
```

One thus adds a constraint (in case the search is **case sensitive**):

```
if w in text
```

Which checks whether `text` *contains* the word `w`.

This gives:

```
>>> count_words(u"How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {u"how", u"are", u"you", u"hello"})
2
```

`"how"` is not counted since `"How"` is not the same as `"how"`

In case the search should be **case-insensitive**, you can use:

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    text = text.lower()
    for w in words:
        w = w.lower()
        if w in text:
            count += 1
    return count
```

which returns you test-case exactly (using `python3`):

```
>>> count_words(u"How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {u"how", u"are", u"you", u"hello"})
3
>>> count_words(u"Bananas, give me bananas!!!", {u"banana", u"bananas"})
2
>>> count_words(u"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",{u"sum", u"hamlet", u"infinity", u"anything"})
1
```

Comment: @qeqweaskjsa: fixed it, replace it by `lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_words(text, words, case_insensitive=False):
    """Returns the number of space-delimited words in `text` that
    appear in some iterable `words`"""

    if case_insensitive:
        text = text.lower()
        words = map(str.lower, words)
    return sum(1 for word in text.split() if word in words)
```

Using that kind of generator expression is a very idiomatic way to construct this function. Basically constructing a list full of `1`s for every word in `text.split()` that is also in `words`, then returning the `sum` of those `int`s

Comment: Note in Python3.3 and newer, [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is probably better than `str.lower`